# How would I use ulogd2 on Ubuntu with IPv6?

Tags: iptables, ipv6

I am trying to make use of ulogd2 (package `ulogd` version `2.0.3-1ubuntu2`) on my Ubuntu server and I run into the problem that `ip6tables` fails:

```
$ ip6tables -A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/sec --limit-burst 15 -j ULOG --ulog-prefix "flt "
ip6tables v1.4.21: unknown option "--ulog-prefix"
```

Now that's peculiar, because `ulogd2` has IPv6 support unlike `ulogd` v1.

```
lsmod|grep -i ULOG
```

shows me the `ipt_ULOG` module loaded. But there is no `ip6t_ULOG` module when I try with `modprobe` and no `xt_ULOG` either.

Any ideas how to enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [the man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/iptables-extensions.8.html), ULOG is deprecated (and IPv4-only). It was replaced with the NFLOG target, which can be used with either protocol.

For example:

```
ip6tables -A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/sec --limit-burst 15 -j NFLOG --nflog-prefix "flt "
```

You still use the ulogd2 daemon with the NFLOG target.

Comment: `ulogd2` still calls its module `ipt_ULOG`, it appears. That is, I am using `ulogd2` which *should* be capable of supporting IPv6, as outlined in my question. Does your answer imply that it is the target inside my netfilter rules which is the sole problem?

Comment: That's what I said!

Comment: Awesome, then this question is answered.